# Group or Chain tasks from different REMOTE celery applications/workers

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I want to experiment on grouping tasks from different celery applications, running on different/remote servers/machines.

So for example, in application 1, running in server 1, I have this task:

```
@app.task(name='func1', bind=True, queue='func1')
def func1(self, args):
    ret = {"func1_status":"success"}
    return ret
```

In application 2, running in server 2, I have this task:

```
@app.task(name='func2', bind=True, queue='func2')
def func2(self, args):
    ret = {"func2_status":"success"}
    return ret
```

Now in application 3, running in server 3, I want to have a task that uses the 2 remote tasks ins a group:

```
from celery import chain, group
from celery.result import allow_join_result

@app.task(name='func3', bind=True, queue='func3')
def func3(self, args):
    ret = None
    res = group(func2.s(args), func1.s(args))()
    with allow_join_result():
        ret = res.get()
    return ret
```

Then I will just add/call a task, via func3, like this:

```
res = func3.delay(args)
```

So the above is what I wanted to do, but I don't know how can I import/call func1 and func2 tasks to be used, remotely, in the group for func3.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!